# Definite Articles vs Non-definite Articles

Tags: definite-articles

1,A chicken I bought yesterday is missing.

2,Her father was shot by a man trying to rob his retail store.

Theoretically, a phrase that refers to something identified uniquely should take a definite article.

Like scenario 1, "A chicken." indicates I bought more than one chicken yesterday. If I only bought one chicken, this sentence should be rephrased as "The " chicken I bought yesterday is missing."

But Scenario 2,   many people feel that "a" doesn't exclude the possibility that there was only one man robbing.
How is this happening?

Comment: The man is unidentified, either because he got away or because his identity isn't revealed in the context of the sentence.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong to say *a chicken*?

Comment: Because I think I have to make a choice between "the" and "a", and , if I had bought only one chicken, "the" sounds more appropriate. Are you suggesting that, in this case, both articles are correct？

Comment: @Robbyzhu Yes, "a chicken" is fine, even if only one chicken is meant.

Comment: If you want to say definitively you bought more than one chicken, you say *one of the chickens I bought yesterday is missing*. Why would native English speakers use *one of the* so often if *a* meant exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **A chicken I bought yesterday is missing.**

The sentence may mean you might have bought  more than one  chicken  or  only one chicken. One of the chickens you bought  or the only chicken  you  bought  is missing

The chicken I bought is missing  may mean you bought one chicken  and  the chicken is  missing.

> **Her father was shot by  a man trying to rob his retail  store**

Her father was shot  by  a man (who was unidentified)
trying  to rob his retail store.

I think this does not mean that only one man tried to rob the store. It  may mean there were some men and one of them shot her  father without being identified.

We can not  say exactly what  happened without knowing  the context. The use of  articles  can not exactly  reveal  the  facts.

Comment: Your use of bold text makes is very difficult to read your answer.